# How to integrate visual studio Analysis Services with MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I had created an Analysis Services in visual studio. Now I am trying to connect it with MVC to retrieve the DataSet. For this I can't able to get any reference. Is this possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i Found the Solution. We can use ADOMD.NET.

ADOMD.NET is a Microsoft .NET Framework data provider that is designed to communicate with Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services.

Refer: Below Links

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123483.aspx
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123477(v=sql.110).aspx